# Show image category Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

a client ask this : display random categories with images.

Im using this code to display Random wp_list_categories on the sidebar :

```
    <?php
//display random sorted list of terms in a given taxonomy
$counter = 0;
$max = 5; //number of categories to display
$taxonomy = 'category';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
shuffle ($terms);
//echo 'shuffled';
if ($terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter <= $max) {
        echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and i'm using this plugin to add images to my categories :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

Question is : How Can I hack the first code to display images with categories ?

Thank you so much for any help :)